# Invoke a specific printer to print C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to call a specific printer to print in my WPF application.
I have three printer
Suppose
Printer1 for Bar bill Print
Printer2 for Kitchen bill Print
Printer3 for Guest bill Print
printers name already saved in database, while printing I get a printer name from DB
and want to print from specific printer, not defaul printer
Here is my code

```
var v = new PrinterDAL().GetPrinterSettings();
try
{
   System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new 
      System.Threading.ThreadStart(
            delegate()
            {   
                gridPrint.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    new Action(
                    delegate()
                    {
                            PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
                            printDialog.PrintQueue = new PrintQueue(
                                new PrintServer(@"\\" + v.BarPrinter), "");
                            printDialog.PrintVisual(gridPrint, "");
                            this.Close();
                    }
                ));
            }
            ));
            thread.Start();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButton.OK, 
                                       MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
```

I get an exception from this code

"An exception occurred while creating the PrintServer object. Win32 error: The printer name is invalid."

Comment: Given that we're not mind readers - what does `v.BarPrinter` contain?

Comment: It contains the name of the printer, which is the error here. Can you print out the name and check why .NET cannot communicate with the printer?

Comment: If the answer is correct. Please check it as accepted. Other people can find the answer in a faster way.

Comment: i have marked as correct

Comment: Doesn't appear as correct in the system. Just a +1 in usefulness. Accept it as best answer... if it looks like the best answer for you, of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PrintServer must be instance using a computer or printer server device in UNC format (`\\resource`) not a printer name:

For example, if the name of your computer, in your domain, is KashifPC and you have configured a printer, called "Printer1", you can use:

```
//example code. no error handling.
PrintServer localPS = New PrintServer(@"\\KashifPC")
PrinterQueue printer1 = localPS.GetPrintQueue("Printer1") //v.BarPrinter???
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.PrintQueue = printer1
//rest of code
```

Comment: jlvaquero you are brilliant..bundle of thanks.it has resolved my problem.i am facing this problem from last three days.........Thanks